# How to create a function which ask for header, and body in back end c# rest api

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, frontend, backend

> Good practices 
>   How to create a rest api function which ask for
>   Headers, and body, and what content is going to set in header and what
>   content is going to be in body?
>
> and how to call this function? (programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a WebClient to access the REST resource in question, you can pass the WebClient and set its headers in a method like this:

`public static void AddBasicAuthRequestHeaders(WebClient webClient, string userId, string password)
        {
            webClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            webClient.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Helper.Base64EncodeString(string.Format("{0}:{1}", userId, password)) + "");
        }`

Since the request body is passed to the WebClient when it is used, you don't need to pass a reference to the client in the method that builds out the request body.

```
    public static string BuildRequestBody(){
 return "{\"Value\":\"?$filter=Name eq '" + objectName + "'&$select=Id\"}";}
```

Then you can use them like so:

```
 using (WebClient webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            bool isSuccessful = false;
            string requestBody = BuildRequestBody();
            AddBasicAuthRequestHeaders(webClient, "myUser", "myPwd");
            try
            {
                string responseString = webClient.UploadString(resourceUrl, requestBody);
                JArray responseArray = JArray.Parse(responseString);
                isSuccessful = (bool)responseArray[0]["IsSuccessful"];
                if (isSuccessful)
                {
                    objectId = (int)responseArray[0]["RequestedObject"]["Id"];
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string logMessage = string.Format("Error retrieving Id for object {0}. Exception: {1}\r\nDetails:{2}", objectName, ex.Message, ex.StackTrace);
                Helper.Log(LogLevel.Error, logMessage);
                throw (ex);
            }
        }
        return objectId;
```

Comment: thanks but my question is about back-end how to program this function? how to set it receives "header" and "body" parameters in c#